# Notoriety for tank, healer, and DPS

Tags: rift

I know that based on the notoriety that you have for specific factions in Rift, you're able to purchase specific items. Outside of Lycini and Torvan Hunters however, what are the most useful factions to max out notoriety in first?

I plan on primarily being a tank with my cleric, so I want to know what notoriety I should focus on first for gearing my tank spec. I'd also like to know which factions are good to max out for DPS and healing specs so that in the future when gearing my secondary specs I'll know what to farm.

Answer (score 2):

I think that for every spec you should farm reputation at factions that unlock you runes(see `RIFT store -> Equipment -> Runes`) which you can't craft on your own - that should be Quajiri, Empyrean Allience, Necropolic caretakers, Eternal City Saviors etc..
I'm sure I missed some out, will update answer later.

If you are asking which runes to get first I suggest getting the lower amount of rep for every you can buy first(if you don't have much plat I suggest buying only the lower ones for 10 plat only) and then focus on the factions with expensive lower ones.

I suggest googling *"Best in slot runes tank cleric"* there are some good guides also on farming the rep.